# why no sound when I use CompositeAudioClip in python moviepy?

Tags: python, audio, video, moviepy

here is the python script.

```
from moviepy.editor import *
videoclip = VideoFileClip("1_0_1522314608.m4v")
audioclip = AudioFileClip("jam_1_Mix.mp3")

new_audioclip = CompositeAudioClip([videoclip.audio, audioclip])
videoclip.audio = new_audioclip
videoclip.write_videofile("new_filename.mp4")
```

then returned

> [MoviePy] >>>> Building video new_filename.mp4 [MoviePy] Writing audio
>   in new_filenameTEMP_MPY_wvf_snd.mp3
>   100%|████████████████████████████████████████| 795/795 [00:01<00:00,
>   466.23it/s] [MoviePy] Done. [MoviePy] Writing video new_filename.mp4 100%|███████████████████████████████████████| 1072/1072 [01:26<00:00,
>   10.31it/s] [MoviePy] Done. [MoviePy] >>>> Video ready: new_filename.mp4

1_0_1522314608.m4v and jam_1_Mix.mp3 they both have sound.

but the new file new_filename.mp4 no sound.

did I do something wrong? please help. thank you.

Comment: Same issue here

Comment: What happens if you write `new_audioclip` to a `.mp3` file with `new_audioclip.write_audiofile("sound.mp3")`. Does it have any sound?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues. I found that sometimes the audio is in fact present, but will not be played by all players. (Quicktime does not work, but VLC does).
I finally use something like :

```
    video_clip.set_audio(composite_audio).write_videofile(
        composite_file_path,
        fps=None,
        codec="libx264",
        audio_codec="aac",
        bitrate=None,
        audio=True,
        audio_fps=44100,
        preset='medium',
        audio_nbytes=4,
        audio_bitrate=None,
        audio_bufsize=2000,
        # temp_audiofile="/tmp/temp.m4a",
        # remove_temp=False,
        # write_logfile=True,
        rewrite_audio=True,
        verbose=True,
        threads=None,
        ffmpeg_params=None,
        progress_bar=True)
```

A few remarks :

- aac seems to work better for quicktime than mp3.
- logfile file generation helps to diagnose what is happening behind the scenes
- temp_audiofile can be tested on its own
- `set_audio()` returns a new clip and leave the object on which it is called unchanged
- Setting the audio clip duration to match the video helps :

  ```
  composite_audio = composite_audio.subclip(0, video_clip.duration)
  composite_audio.set_duration(video_clip.duration)
  ```